# Currency switcher isn't working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, multicurrency

I used custom theme by Plazma theme in my magento website,
in home page when i select currency from header it changes and rates and only in few sections,

For example, there are three sliders available in home page,
      1). Sale Off
      2). Featured Products
      3). New Products

when i select currency it changes rates of products only in Sale off slider, remaining slider remains unchanged.

I noticed weird issue that is when open any product, and in product view page and category listing page it converts currency rates.
Only issues in home page.
i flushed all caches, but no luck

Any help would be appreciate.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ain't sure but, I think its issue just because may be your theme has put hardcoded Price.

Change it to below, Than check It should work.

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($price, true, false) ?>
```

User above Code use yout price variable.